# TinyMCE file_browser_callback not showing browse button

Tags: tinymce

I am unable to get the TinyMCE `file_browser_callback` property to work, so that the Image dialog shows a browse button.

I downloaded TinyMCE 5.08 from tiny.cloud (prod version). I insert the library, then call `init()` below. I added a `file_browser_callback` property with a callback function, which is supposed to open a modal window, from where I pick up a file from a media library and insert it back.

For reasons I cannot understand I cannot make the **browse** button, in the image dialog, visible.

```
     <script src="{{ asset('js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js') }}"></script>
     <script>
        $(function() {
            tinymce.init({
                height: 500,
                selector: 'textarea.wysiwyg',
                plugins: ['image'],
                branding: false,
                convert_urls: false,
                file_browser_callback:   function(field_name, url, type, win) {
                    $('#file-modal').modal({
                        duration: 200,
                        onApprove: function () {
                            if ($('#file-modal .file.selected').length) {
                                let $file = $('#file-modal .file.selected');
                                win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = $file.data('path');
                            }
                        }
                    }).modal('show');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The browse button should appear when the callback exists. I've tried implementing the callback as a separate function and passingit as a string with no luck. There are no error messages visible in the console.

I also tried 5.07 with no luck. I have this working on a separate application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API you are using is a TinyMCE 4 API. Per the migration documentation, in TinyMCE 5 you need to use `file_picker_callback` instead:

- https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/migration-from-4x/#file_browser_callbackfile_picker_callback
- https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#file_picker_callback

Comment: Thanks! This was it. I got it working with very small changes (adding a callback with file path from the file library)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears TinyMCE dropped the support for file_browser_callback from their 5.x versions. Propably because they offer file hosting cloud services themselves now and it might be a premium plugin. What a fantastic solution. I'll fall back to using 4.9.4 prod version.

Comment: Support for file picking was not dropped.  Per the migration docs the API changed:  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/migration-from-4x/#file_browser_callbackfile_picker_callback

Comment: We didn't drop it because we offer our own. We dropped it because `file_browser_callback` had been deprecated (although admittedly poorly documented as such) since it was replaced by `file_picker_callback` in June 2014.